# WebApi Core 2.2 OData resource/path not found

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I'm using WebApi Core 2.2.  The Microsoft OData Client is adding a new parent record plus a subrecord (Deal+DealFee) from a WPF application.  I'm hosting in IIS on Windows 10.

When I call container.SaveChanges(), it successfully calls the service to add the parent Deal record, but then it does a SECOND POST operation to this url (this is generated by the MS odata client lib):

```
POST http://localhost/mysite/odata/Deals(14)/DealFees
```

(note this includes the ID 14 which was just generated when adding the Deal)

This is two separate POSTs from the MS odata client lib, not a "deep insert" apparently.  However, this results in a 404 (NotFound), which I can observe in Fiddler.  The following urls DO work perfectly:

```
/odata/Deals
/odata/Deals(14)
/odata/DealFees
```

It seems like either the WebApi Core 2.2 service is not handling the POST to /Deals(14)/DealFees path, OR /Deals(14)/DealFees isn't a valid odata Uri?  Is this kind of path generally supported in OData?

I don't know.  Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Deep insert is not supported in WebAPI OData as of now. To me, it seems like the client is updating the resource set and the resource set for the navigation with two separate post requests and the reason you are getting a 404 is that there is no action mapped to the second request URI in the service.

The service can support this either by introducing a PostToDealFeesFromDeals controller action with default OData routing convention or use attribute routing to map the action for such requests.

If the action already exists then it might be that the first request did not finish creating the new record and the second request was fired, hence 404.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So do I put PostToDealFeesFromDeals on the DealsController?  Does the default OData routing somehow map that to the path I gave automatically?

Comment: BTW, I ended up just implementing OData functions DeepInsert() and DeepUpdate() in my controller.  Far easier than fighting Microsoft's incomplete and buggy implementations.